# void pointer to vector of boost shared pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i have a void pointer

```
void *vp;
```

I want to point it to `vec_A` inside a function where `vec_A` is passed as a reference, that is

```
some_function(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> >& vec_A)
{
   void *vp;
   //now i want vp to point to vec_A
}
```

and after I point `vp` to `vec_A`, how to I get it back as

```
 std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> >
```

Comment: `void *vp = static_cast<void*>(&vec_A);` But why oh why?

Comment: @jrok parameter for a thread start procedure would be a good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Address-of and cast:

```
void * vp = &vec_A;   // address-of

std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<A> > & v =
     *static_cast< std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<A> >* >(vp);
```

Now `v` is a reference to the very same vector whose address you took in the line above.